# How can I use a variable as an attribute name in terraform 3.0?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to somehow create an arbitrary attribute from a variable? Here is what I am trying to achieve.

How I currently do it (now deprecated in 3.0.0):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "example" {
  condition {
    field  = var.condition_field
    values = var.condition_values
  }
}
```

The new syntax requires a nested block with the condition field. But my condition is stored in a variable:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "example" {
  condition {
    var.condition_field {
      values = var.condition_values
    }
  }
}
```

---

Is it possible to somehow create an arbitrary attribute from a variable?

or: Can I store a nested attribute block in a variable?

---

Background on my question: I am currently trying to upgrade from 2.70.0 to 3.0.0 and there are quite a few breaking changes in my system. One of them includes the `aws_lb_listener_rule`.  If it is not possible to create the attribute from the variable I would have to either pin the version or change the module API used by a ton of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems like it is not possible to do that. The closes thing I have found that allows me to use 3.0.0 without changing my module variables and with that all the Terraform scripts that use it are dynamic conditional blocks.

```
dynamic "condition" {
  for_each = var.field == "path-pattern" ? [var.field] : []
  content {
    path_pattern {
      values = var.patterns
    }   
  }
}
```

This is repeated for all possible `var.field` values.